# Smart Contract failed to load Web3 with truffle

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle

I'm trying to create a ETH smart contract with solidity 0.5.10, truffle and web3. Everything seems to work well except that I get:

> ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library definition.
>
> ```
> const web3 = require('web3');
> ```

When I'm trying to load web3.

I have installed web3 (dir {project folder} npm install web3) and in my package.json (located in my project folder) :

```
"dependencies": {
   "web3": "^1.3.4"
}
```

I've tried both:

```
import Web3 from 'web3';
```

And

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
```

But it still can't load web3, what do I do wrong?

contract that cause the error

```
pragma solidity 0.5.10;

const web3 = require('web3');

contract UserRepository {

  struct User {
      uint id;
      bytes32 firstName;
      bytes32 lastName;
  }
  mapping(uint => User) public users;

  uint public latestUserId = 0;
  address private owner;

  constructor() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "helloworld",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "truffle-config.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "web3": "^1.3.4"
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing node.js into your Solidity code.

```
pragma solidity 0.5.10;

const web3 = require('web3'); // this is node.js

contract UserRepository {
```

Remove the `const web3 = require('web3');` line and it's going to compile successfully *(tested in Remix)*.

---

Here I'm just guessing that you wanted to use `web3` to enable JS code to communicate with your smart contract (e.g. for test purposes).

If that's the case, you need to create a separate JS file that imports `web3` and instantiates this contract using [web3.eth.Contract](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth-contract.html).

Or since you're already using Truffle for compilation, you can use their [test tools](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/testing/writing-tests-in-javascript) for JS tests of smart contracts.